# Export CSV without crash from node js

Tags: node.js, export-to-csv, nodejs-stream, json2csv

I need to export CSV for large amount of data, like it's having 100k rows, I'm using [Json2CSV](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) but sometimes it's taking a long time and crashed. I'm using node js stream but no use. I am googling but I don't have idea to clear it.Please any one can guide me how can I fix it.

Node JS

```
var formatedData = {......} //object with data

let filename = 'test' + '.csv';

let pathName = await writeToCSV(filename, formatedData, fields);

let readStream = fs.createReadStream(pathName);

res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${filename}`);
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

let downloadStream = readStream.pipe(res);

    fields = null;
    formatedData = null;
    downloadStream.on('finish', function() {
    fs.unlink(pathName, function() {});
        downloadStream = null;
        readStream = null;
});
```

writeToCSV

```
  function writeToCSV(filename, data, fields, option) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (typeof data !== 'object') {
            return reject(new Error('Data is not an object'));
        }

        let options = {
            fields
        };

        if (typeof option === 'object') {
            for (let key in option) {
                options[key] = option[key];
            }
        }

        let tmpPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', tmp);
        let pathFile = tmpPath + filename;

        return Promise.all([Promise.resolve(json2csv(data, options).split('\n')), checkTMPExist(tmpPath)]).then(data => {

            let csvFormat = data[0];

            let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(pathFile);

            csvFormat.forEach((lines, index) => {
                if (index === csvFormat.length - 1) {
                    writeStream.end(lines + '\n');
                } else {
                    writeStream.write(lines + '\n');
                }
            });

            writeStream.on('finish', function() {
                this.end();
                return resolve(pathFile);
            });

            writeStream.on('error', function(err) {
                this.end();
                fs.unlink(pathFile, () => {});
                return reject(err);
            });

        }).catch(err => {
            fs.unlink(pathFile, () => {});
            return reject(err);
        });

    });
}
```

Front end Ajax call

```
function export_csv(url, fileName) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            var encodedUri = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(result);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
            link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log("Export csv have some issue:" + JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });
}
```